# Trigger a jQuery event on a target div (specefic class in an span id)

Tags: jquery, triggers, click, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname

I'm currently trying to associate a click to a right arrow press in a web application. The thing I have here is working, but pops me every single `.t-input` in my page every single time I click my button. I'm currently using this code :

```
        comboboxArrowDown.onclick = function () {
            var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
            e.which = 39; // Key arrow right = 39
            $('.t-input').trigger(e);
        }
```

This code is working because I'm referring directly to the input class which is : 't-input'. Now, what I want to do is select the input to use. The hard part here, is that different boxes have the same input class name and I can't change that.

Can you explain how to resolve this if my input is in a span with and id="a", which contain a div called class="b" , which contain another div called class="c", and then my input.

I tried to use

```
document.getElementById("a").getElementsByClassName("t-input")[0]
```

but I can't use `.trigger` on it...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are mixing pure javascript and jQuery.

span with and id="a",

```
#a
```

which contain a div called class="b"

`.b`

, which contain another div called class="c"

`.c`

, and then my input

```
.t-input

$("#a > .b > .c > .t-input")
```

This will get all the objects with class .t-input INSIDE .c INSIDE .b INSIDE the element with id #a

The other answers given will surely get you the same result, but the b could be inside the c or the c inside the b.

Comment: If you refer to my picture. Can you explain to me what happen since i have some space in each "a", "b" and "c" statement that I used!

Comment: Don't worry about the spaces. But but the dots immediately before the class name text.

Comment: I posted another picture of the complete path to get to my ".t-input" input. Can you tell me the correct path for it ! Here's the picture : 
http://i.stack.imgur.com/MOxKp.png

Comment: It depends how specific you need to be in the filtering.

Comment: This would be very specific `$('#tableAutresPlacements > .t-grid-header > .t-alt > [tdid = nom] > [tdid = spanTauxGaranti] > #AutresPlacements_1__Terme-Validation > .t-widget > .t-dropdown-wrap > .t-input')`

Comment: It might be a lot easier to use $(this) , see: http://html-tuts.com/jquery-this-selector/

Comment: For a reason that I don't understand, it's only working with 
$(".t-input").trigger(e);
but opens every box in my page.
the code you provided looked perfect, but doesn't open my box :S

Comment: I figured that everything is working before this : #AutresPlacements_1__Terme-Validation
I don't know if that gives you an idea !

Comment: $('#tableAutresPlacements > .t-grid-header > .t-alt > [tdid = nom] > [tdid = spanTauxGaranti] > span > .t-widget > .t-dropdown-wrap > .t-input')

Comment: I think you are making it too complicated.

Comment: I fixed the first answer you gave to me and now it's working find ! I just have one last question ! Since my "AutresPlacements_Placements_1__Terme-Validation" is in a for loop. Can i replace the "1" with i? I'm used to code in c# so i can use ({0}, i) but i don't think it's working here !

Comment: Try       `comboboxArrowDown.onclick = function () {
            var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
            e.which = 39; // Key arrow right = 39
            $(this).trigger(e);
        }`

Comment: $(this) is not working since i'm not pressing down my right arrow directly where I click !

Comment: Maybe you could use a jQuery wildcard like  `[id^=AutresPlacements_]` meaning roughly "everything where id attribute begins with AutresPlacements_"

Answer (score 0):

```
$("span#a div.b div.c .t-input").trigger(e);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fact that you said id="a" and class="b":

```
comboboxArrowDown.onclick = function () {
            var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
            e.which = 39; // Key arrow right = 39
            $('#a.b.c input').trigger(e);
        }
```

If this is not working or is unclear, to be able to provide you with a better answer, please provide the actual html structure/code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Here is a link to the complete HTML code. Can you please give me the path to get to the input "t-input"!
HTML : http://i.stack.imgur.com/MOxKp.png

Answer (score 0):

@grateful, is there a way to do the samething but with the comboboxesArrowDown variable. Because i'm using the document.querySelectorAll method to find it, but I also need to specify the path! Here is the code:

```
    var comboboxesArrowDown = document.querySelectorAll(".t-icon.t-arrow-down");
    for (var i = 0; i < comboboxesArrowDown.length; i++)
    {
        var comboboxArrowDown = comboboxesArrowDown[i];
        comboboxArrowDown.onclick = function () 
        {
            var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
            e.which = 39; // Right arrow key (Keycode #39)
            $("#AutresPlacements_Placements_1__Terme-Validation > .t-widget > .t-dropdown-wrap > .t-input").trigger(e);
        }
    }
```